# How does AbstractQueuedSynchronizer building block of concurrent api does not have anything synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I am trying to understand at a high level how java's concurrent API built using `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` as a building block. I didn't see any use of `synchronized`, `wait()` + `notify()` inside this class. Then how it is possible to achieve a thread-safe code?

Although I saw `unsafe` CAS operations to achieve some atomicity, but that is not enough to have fully thread safe code.

Comment: *Although i saw unsafe.CAS opertions to achieve some atomicity but that is not enough to have fully thread safe code.*           WHY?

Comment: @xingbin - this is what i am trying to understand, so lets say i want to guard a block of code then without synchronization how can i do that with just CAS operations , because to guard it i will have to acquire some lock ?

Comment: CAS already guarantees memory visibility. Are you looking for mutual exclusion? Let's say you have an `AtomicBoolean` `isLockAcquired` which determines if any thread is holding the lock. Then you could implement mutual exclusion by: Try CAS `isLockAcquired` from false to true. If that succeeds the thread now holds the lock, to unlock it sets `isLockAcquired` to false. If it fails, repeat CAS in a loop, possibly sleep until notified that the lock was released and then try CAS again. Though the `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` implementation appears to be more complex.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Unsafe`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java) class is not as well documented as classes publicly exposed by the JDK, so not all guarantees its methods make are obvious.

However, if you look at the [latest source code of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java), you will see that it now uses `VarHandle` whose methods are well documented. For `compareAndSet` the documentation [says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#compareAndSet(java.lang.Object...)):

> Atomically sets the value of a variable to the newValue with the memory semantics of setVolatile(java.lang.Object...) if the variable's current value, referred to as the witness value, == the expectedValue, as accessed with the memory semantics of getVolatile(java.lang.Object...).

This means there will not be race conditions since for two concurrent threads only one thread will update the value, the other will fail. And you get the needed memory visibility guarantees.